# vIM comments are automatically indented in a wrong way

Tags: macos, vim

Currently when pressing `i` + `//` to add a comment line on vIM (on OSX), the `//` characters get indented at 8 spaces instead of being indented correctly according to the adequate nesting level of indentation.

I have already tried to disable the auto-indentation of comments by using:

`autocmd FileType * setlocal formatoptions-=c formatoptions-=r formatoptions-=o"`

But it didn't work.

I don't have any idea of why this is happening.
Here is an example of the wrong indentation:

```
function code() {
    var bla = 'bla';
        // I just pressed i + // and this happened
    // This is where it should have been
}
```

PS.: This .vimrc file was working in another computer, it just doesn't on this OSX.

Comment: Show us your `vimrc`.

Answer (score 0):

The 'formatoptions' option does not tell Vim when to indent, it tells Vim when to wrap lines.

I suspect either your indent settings (indentexpr, cindent, smartindent) are not what you expect, or your shiftwidth/tabstop/softtabstop settings don't match what you expect, or both.

Check the current settings, and which script set them that way, with:

```
:verbose set indentexpr? cindent? smartindent? shiftwidth? tabstop? softtabstop?
```

Your shiftwidth, tabstop, and softtabstop should usually all match each other, and match the amount of indentation you normally add. Your indent settings should usually be based on filetype for most users (you don't mention what filetype you're editing so that's as specific as I can get).

Comment: Here is my .vimrc
http://pastebin.com/kL6VAC2U

I'm actually trying to edit javascript.
I just researched about all the options you just said I should check and they seem to be correct. The automatic indent is wrong only after trying to insert `//` in a new line.

Comment: Are they "correct" specifically after you see the bad behavior, while still editing that file? What is "correct"? For me, the indent setting for a javascript file is just 'cindent'; 'indentexpr' is empty. And, it works fine for me. My tabstop, softtabstop, and shiftwidth are all set to 2.

Comment: 'cindent' is off but they are all set to 4 (which is what I would like).
'indentexpr' however is not empty. It points to a plugin path.
I'll try removing it and see what I can do, thanks for the help.